# Neo4j performance - slow queries using cypher and REST

Tags: neo4j

We have a graph with 60M (with one property per node) nodes and 300 relationships. 
When we tried to query FOAF, the results were very slow - 20-40 seconds (depenads on how many relationships the user have)

Our Neo version is 2.0.0-M05 and Neo server is CentOs6, 8 cores (4x2 CPU), 64GB RAM.

The is the query we're using:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(user_id = 'test') 
MATCH n-[:FRIEND_OF*2..2]-friend_of_friend 
WHERE not(n-[:FRIEND_OF]-friend_of_friend) RETURN friend_of_friend.user_id, COUNT(*) 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC limit 20;
```

We tried execute the query using REST with parameters - but still it takes a lot of time.

Neo Parameters we changed:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=3G
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=15G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=3G
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=100M
```

And also change the JVM param -

```
wrapper.java.maxmemory=32768
```

This doesn't look like normal behavior. What could be the root cause of this?
How can we improve query time ?

This is the profile output:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["friend_of_friend.user_id", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEc9bc16db-8fc8-4aba-a4fc-04789a2a712d"], returnItemNames=["friend_of_friend.user_id", "COUNT(*)"], _rows=50, _db_hits=0)
==> Top(orderBy=["SortItem(Cached(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEc9bc16db-8fc8-4aba-a4fc-04789a2a712d of type Long),false)", "SortItem(Cached(friend_of_friend.user_id of type Any),true)"], limit="Literal(50)", _rows=50, _db_hits=0)
==>   EagerAggregation(keys=["Cached(friend_of_friend.user_id of type Any)"], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEc9bc16db-8fc8-4aba-a4fc-04789a2a712d,CountStar())"], _rows=7142, _db_hits=0)
==>     Extract(symKeys=["friend_of_friend", "n", "  UNNAMED62"], exprKeys=["friend_of_friend.user_id"], _rows=12969, _db_hits=12969)
==>       Filter(pred="NOT(PatternPredicate((friend_of_friend)-[  UNNAMED109:FRIEND_OF]-(n)}))", _rows=12969, _db_hits=0)
==>         TraversalMatcher(trail="(n)-[:FRIEND_OF*2..2]-(friend_of_friend)", _rows=16455, _db_hits=16810)
```

Comment: Could you profile the query in webadmin console or bin/neo4j-shell (just put `PROFILE ` before the query) and post the results?

Comment: I added the profile output, thanks.